# How to unselect selected item in js?

Tags: magento-1.7, javascript

`<img class="swatch-img current" src="IMAGEURL" alt="XXX " title="XXX ">`this is source line.

`if class = current` onclick it should be changed to `class=""`

I wanna change do it in javascript.

Comment: what actually you wanna do  ??

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what version of Magento you're using: v1 or v2. There will be different ways to add the following code to the page based on the version. Here is some JavaScript that should do the trick:

```
(function () {
    var images = document.querySelectorAll('swatch-img');

    for (var i = 0, item; item = images[i]; i--) {
        images.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
            var el = event.target;

            if (el.classList.contains('current') {
                el.classList.remove('current');
            }
        }
    }
}());
```